# vnstat reporting different data usage than provider

Tags: networking, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using vnstat 1.11 on an older Ubuntu 14.04 server. My hosting provider gives me a monthly metered bill for the combine up- and download data. I'm trying to get a better sense of what the balance is between up and downloaded data (over longer periods, `vnstat`, `vnstat -m`) and what is happening at any moment (`vnstat -l`, `vnstat -h`). So far, things are working great.

**However, vnstat is measuring significantly less data throughput on my network than my provider, about 5x less (roughly 200GB vs 1TB).**

I've been in touch with my provider, and although they have tried to help pinpoint the problem, they assume that the problem lies with my measurements, not theirs.

#### Things I've tried

- Install another tool to measure data for a longer period *(I've tried slurm, but if there's a better alternative please, let me know). Measurements seem to be roughly the same.*
- Check if another interface is handling data *(nope, there are two, but only one is external)*
- Check if backups are somehow measured *(they're not, the snapshots are not network traffic)*
- Measure if the data input/output is somewhat reasonable

This last step is interesting: I've measured the increase in disk space over a period of several hours (I know that nothing (big) was deleted in this timeframe) and measured the incoming data during that same period. They are almost exactly the same, so at least the upload measuments seem reliable.

**Any suggestions for:**

- Validating the download measurements? They are in sync with office hours (hardly any download traffic outside office hours) which is as expected.
- Where vnstat might be misconfigured?
- Other tools to check if vnstat is the culprit?

Comment: Ask the provider for a breakdown of the data/how its calculated.  Maybe they are lumping other IPs in with your ranges?   Even if not, at least it will give you an idea how/what they are measuring, so you can investigate further.

Comment: @davidgo I've tried but they won't go into more detail than to say that they measure  'all traffic going in and out of this specific machine's WAN interface' (the `eth0` on this machine). They are a reputable provider and it seems unlikely that they would measure things incorrectly (or that I'm the first to notice), so before blaming them I want to figure out what can go wrong on my end.

Comment: Out if curiosity, what country, what ISP? Unrelatedly, you could put in a router that does byte counting or setup cacti or some other graphing system using SNMP. You might also be able to roll something together using iptables counters. (Ive done all the above in my life!)

Comment: @davidgo turns out the provider was right (see my answer below) but thank you for your thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was going wrong, and it was indeed my fault.

#### The solution

In the `/etc/vnstat.conf`, I changed this line

```
MaxBandwidth 100
```

to

```
MaxBandwidth 1000
```

**How I found out**

I thought I'd dive a bit deeper into the spaghetti of logs. I've inherited this poorly maintained legacy machine, so it took a bit of time to go through the immense amount of noise that was being logged. After silencing/fixing most of the messages and looking for clues in the remainder, I came across this entry:

`vnstat: Traffic rate for "eth0" higher than set maximum 100 Mbit`

It turns out that my 1Gbit connection was measured as 100Mbit. For uploads, this was not noticeable since they rarely (if ever) exceeded 100Mbit. Downloads, however, are quite a bit faster but they were being cut off at the 100Mbit mark (so any transfer faster than that was simply not counted).

After setting this to 1000, the measurements shot up, and are now virtually the same as reported by my provider.

For [newer versions of vnstat](https://github.com/vergoh/vnstat/blob/master/cfg/vnstat.conf), this is set to 1000 by default but the older version that comes with this ancient 14.04 install still had 100...

Comment: Newer versions of vnStat will also autodetect the interface specific bandwidth value (when the interface provides such information), reducing the need to change the default settings. Note that even the latest version of vnStat can be compiled and installed in Ubuntu 14.04 due to the short list of needed dependencies.